# Miembro de estructura como parámetro de función

Tags: c, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
typedef struct nodo{
    int matricula, edad;
    char nombre[20];
    float peso, altura;
    struct nodo *next;
} PERSON;
```

y un puntero:

```
PERSON *aux;
```

Lo que busco es hacer una función que calcule el promedio de cada miembro, obviamente excluyendo `matricula`, `nombre` y `next`, pero no sé si, como hay datos tanto `int` como `float`, sea posible hacerlo en la misma función.

Como he visto otras preguntas, he seguido los ejemplos y uso:

```
float promedio(int *miembro){ ... }
```

Pero cuando la mando a llamar escribo:

```
promedio(aux->edad);
```

o debo usar:

```
promedio(&aux->edad);
```

O cuál es el problema? Es porque edad es `int` y `*miembro` es flotante? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `promedio` tiene que calcular el promedio de **todos** los elementos de la lista, luego es facil ver que si tu únicamente le pasas una edad no va a funcionar.

La función tiene que recibir la lista, y dado que tu lista es directamente un puntero (no está embutida en una estructura), sería deseable también indicar el número de elementos a tratar:

```
float promedio(PERSON* miembros, int num_elementos)
```

Así, la función tiene que iterar por la colección `miembros` y, para cada elemento, coger su edad y trabajar con ella:

```
float promedio(PERSON* miembros, int num_elementos)
{
  int total_edad = 0;
  for( int i=0; i<num_elementos; i++ )
    total_edad += miembros->edad;

  return ((float)total_edad)/num_elementos;
}
```

Es necesario forzar la conversión a `float` de uno de los dos elementos para que la división devuelva decimales.

Y algo similar tendrías que hacer para el promedio del peso y la altura:

```
float promedio_peso(PERSON* miembros, int num_elementos)
{
  float total_peso = 0;
  for( int i=0; i<num_elementos; i++ )
    total_peso += miembros->peso;

  return total_peso/num_elementos;
}
```

Como `peso` es de tipo `float` no tiene sentido que `total_peso` sea de tipo `int`, luego ya no es necesario forzar la conversión al hacer la división.

Comment: ya veo, gracias!